# UITableViewController won't customize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, uitableview

I am trying to customize a class using Parse called PFQueryTableViewController. It doesn't seem to want to customize my cells, though:

```
-  (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"UserPhoto";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"title";   
    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 25;
}
return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FeedCustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FeedCustom"];
}

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

// This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
[super objectsWillLoad];

// This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
NSLog(@"Done");
}


// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to     query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

NSLog(@"%@", query);
return query;

}



// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


FeedCustomCell *cell = (FeedCustomCell * )[self.tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FeedCustom" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell
cell.caption.text = [object objectForKey:@"title"];


cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


return cell;

}
```

Any ideas? FeedCustomCell is simply a subclass for UITableViewCell that uses IB to add a label. TableView for my subclass of PFQueryTableViewController is also being created via IB.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your customization in "`viewDidLoad`" instead of the init method, where the xib hasn't been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You need to load cell from bundle using

> [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

either in your cellForRowAtIndexPath or in your init and awake from nib method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FeedCustomCell *cell = (FeedCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BDCustomCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FeedCustomCellXib" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```